# Facebook signup IOS parse

Tags: ios, swift, email, facebook, login

Buenas tardes:
Cuando logró hacer signup y login con Facebook me guarda el id en Parse pero no me guarda el email del usuario utilizado de Facebook para registrarse. Utilizó oauth en Parse server pero no se porque no aparece el email en el mismo a pesar de dar permisos de email en sus creacio. Ley permission = [email]
Cuál es el problema? Gracias

Comment: El email no viene en la autentificación, este lo tienes que recuperar en otra petición a facebook, siempre y cuando si te hayan otorgado el permiso para leerlo. Esto al menos en la versión del API que llegue a trabajar, espero no haya cambiado

Comment: Efectivamente con el método fbsdkgraphrequest puedo pedir por ejemplo username y email y luego añadirlo o cambiarlo en Parse server. Lo conseguí por fin

Comment: Que bueno que ya lo hayas conseguido. Si gustas puedes publicar tu respuesta para ayudar futuros usuarios y ganar reputación

Comment: el buen @Jano respondió a tu pregunta, ¿Fue de utilidad? De ser cierto, click en el check verde, así ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Os dejo aqui todo el proceso, es tal cual lo hago yo en mis aplicaciones:

```
- (void)loginFB {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"]fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,email"}]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    // GUARDAR DATOS
                    NSString *userID    = result[@"id"];
                    NSString *userName  = result[@"name"];
                    NSString *userEmail = result[@"email"];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Primero me logueo con "FBSDKGraphRequest" pidiendo los permisos y si el usuario los acepta, hago la petición de los datos que deseo con "FBSDKGraphRequest" y una vez obtenidos los paso a sus variable, las cuales ya guardas en tu base de datos.

Espero os sirva.